# Anyone know of an API I can get historical price time series for multiple coins

Tags: api, trading, exchange-rate, buy-bitcoins, raw-data

I'd like to build some historical price charts, to use in my [cryptocoin portfolio tracking app](http://coinfox.co), using time series data (with HighCharts js).

Anyone know of an API that provides this price data, preferably for multiple coins (btc, ltc, eth, etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the data on crypto compare

```
const endpoint = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG&extraParams=CryptoCompare&fsym='+ ticker.toUpperCase() +'&limit=365&tryConversion=false&tsym=' + currency.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 17):

I am developing the ccxt cryptocurrency trading library, check it out on GitHub:

https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt

It is a library for cryptocurrency trading and e-commerce with support for many bitcoin/ether/altcoin exchange markets and merchant APIs.

With it you can access market data and trade bitcoin, ether and altcoins with more than 70 (!!!) cryptocurrency exchanges. It is used to connect and trade with crypto markets and payment processing services worldwide. It provides quick access to market data for storage, analysis, visualization, indicator development, trading strategy backtesting, bot programming, building trading algorithms on top of it, webshop integration and related software engineering.

The codebase is in JavaScript / Python (2 and 3) / PHP. You can deploy it from PyPI, with npm (for Node.js) or by cloning the GitHub repository.

The ccxt library is under heavy development right now, but already offers a quick-start for trading and technical analysis with many crypto exchange markets out of the box. It is intended to be used by coders, developers and financial analysts to build algotrading strategies on top of it.

[image]

Comment: You have copy & pasted this answer on a bunch of questions. Self-promotion is fine on stackexchanges, but please provide a specific & relevant answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it actually offers one of possible answers to the question. Doesn't ccxt API provide data that was requested by the original author in the first place? Moreover, the library fetches that data from first-hands, namely the exchanges themselves, which is very nice, not from just some aggregator. I thought it would be useful right here. Yes, I copypasted the answer, but I did that to relevant questions only. So, it's not entirely self-promotion, otherwise it would be useless and my answer would not get any points from stackexchanges' users, right? My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.cryptocoincharts.info
Advance API to more than 100 exchanges: cryptocurrency pricing, OHLC and volume data from multiple exchanges.
BTC38, BTCC, BTER, Bit2C, Bitfinex, Bitstamp, Bittrex, CCEDK, Cexio, Coinbase, Coinfloor, Coinse, Coinsetter, Cryptopia, Cryptsy, Gatecoin, Gemini, HitBTC, Huobi, itBit, Kraken, LakeBTC, LocalBitcoins, MonetaGo, OKCoin, Poloniex, Yacuna, Yunbi, Yobit, Korbit, BitBay, BTCMarkets, QuadrigaCX, CoinCheck, BitSquare, Vaultoro, MercadoBitcoin, Unocoin, Bitso, BTCXIndia, Paymium, TheRockTrading, bitFlyer, Quoine, Luno, EtherDelta, Liqui, bitFlyerFX, BitMarket, LiveCoin, Coinone, Tidex, Bleutrade, EthexIndia and the list seems to grow every day.

Answer (score 1):

[ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api) offers a full API for getting historical tick and OHLCV candle data from the Bittrex exchange. You can sort, order, and get data between specific dates. Supported returned formats are a JSON object or CSV for easily importing into any app.