# Get Historical Bitcoin Prices on GDAX in CSV Format

Tags: exchange-rate, java, historical-trade-data

I'm looking for minute by minute historical Bitcoin price data for the past year in format: time, open, high, low etc.

I code in Java and I'm not familiar with other programming languages (such as python and PHP).

I've read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52674/anyone-know-of-an-api-i-can-get-historical-price-time-series-for-multiple-coins/53413) (and [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/748/where-can-i-get-historic-data-series-of-bitcoin-prices)) thread with the following suggestions:

1. https://min-api.cryptocompare.com - I do not see GDAX listed as one of the supported exchanges (based on this link https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/) (unless the data from Coinbase is exactly the same as the data from GDAX? I know GDAX is the parent company of Coinbase but not sure if trading data is exactly the same..) Also, I tried using this API and it seems to limit the history to several days. I was not able to get a year's worth of minute by minute data for Bitcoin USD pair.
2. https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt - this seems to be trading library written in python and PHP (but no Java support). Also I'm not sure if this allows you to retrieve historical prices or only place trades via various exchanges.
3. https://bitcoincharts.com/t/trades.csv?symbol=gdaxUSD&start=1312174800 returns 404 not found error.
4. http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/ - I do see Coinbase listed but not GDAX (unless they are one in the same?). Also this is tick by tick data, not minute by minute correct?

Some of the other threads I read are about mtGox not gdax or only provide daily reports so I'm not including them.

If I missed any other resources I would much appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you get a good way to get this data? I wrote something quick in mathematica to get the data per minute from the GDAX API, but there are some missing data at random times.

Comment: ad 4: GDAX and Coinbase is the same :-) This is fine resolution data for each trade! But unfortunatelly there is no info whether particular trade is buy or sell.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first ever response on any forum so I hope you find this helpful.

I think your question is "is it possible to get one year worth minute by minute data from gdax?". I only recently started trading with gdax via it's API but i have been trading with kraken's API for a while now and my experience with all crypto currencies so far is that you can only get a few days worth of historical data or ticks. However, if you want minute by minute data from the API, then you will have to query the data at some interval (maybe every minute). Note that the frequency of such queries are usually limited by a rate limit often determined by the exchange.

Also, I do not think Coinbase is an exchange in the sense conventional sense. I see coinbase and gdax as different business units of the same enity. Hence, I suspect that whatever trade or tick information you get from either of the two will be the same. However, they function differently and have two different category of people they cater to. Coinbase API is primarily for building phone applications with only basic features e.g. buy, sell, send, historical data.

However, gdax caters to the more sophisticated trader with more advanced features like limit order, margin trading, OHLC data etc.

You should check the links below to see if there are features that may attend to your needs

https://developers.coinbase.com/
https://docs.gdax.com/?javascript#introduction